# How to remove transparency from Edge dialogs?

Tags: microsoft-edge

[image: Edge transparency]

As you can see this dialog is not very legible. Is there a way to disable this effect?

Help/About tells me: Version 103.0.1264.77 (Official build) (64-bit)
I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: This doesn't happen on my systems. What add-ons do you have in Edge, or what display "hacks" have you installed for Windows (e.g., Aero Glass for Windows 10, Glass2k, etc.)?

Comment: Also does not happen on my systems.  Try (1) Repairing Edge and (2) Light theme.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by following this thread: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/edge-transparent-menus/m-p/3198790

I've disabled Win 11 acrylic effects and set the ANGLE graphics backend to D3D11on12:
[image: Edge flags]

I no longer have these problems.